# watir-webdriver step through a table and save the :title fields

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I would like to step through a table and save the `:title` field there is no text
This is from the *tinymce* website.

```
<table class="mceColorSplitMenu" role="presentation">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a id="_mce_item_3" href="javascript:;" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" title="Black" data-mce-color="#000000" role="option" tabindex="0"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a id="_mce_item_4" href="javascript:;" style="background-color: rgb(153, 51, 0);" title="Burnt orange" data-mce-color="#993300" role="option" tabindex="-1"></a>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
```

Both the following code snipets give me an empty array

```
table_array = Array.new
table = b.table(:class => 'mceColorSplitMenu')
table.rows.each do |row|
 row_array = Array.new
 row.cells.each do |cell|
 row_array << cell.title
 puts(cell.title)
 end
 table_array << row_array
end

t2 = Array.new
b.table(:class => 'mceColorSplitMenu').to_a # this is empty because there is no text field.
```

I am not sure why the `cell.title` is blank.  The first cell has `'title="Black"'`.  I would like to save a **unique** field in each cell to go back later and click each color in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML, the `<a>` tags have `title` attributes.  This snippet should return an array of titles from links in the table:

```
titles = []
b.table(:class => 'mceColorSplitMenu').links.each { |link| titles << b.link(:id => "#{link.id}").title }
```

Edit:

```
titles = b.table(:class => 'mceColorSplitMenu').links.collect(&:title)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The solution worked great.  Do you know if there are tutorials around for this type of complex statement or is this more of a 'school of hard knock' knowledge base?  I would not think of writing code that way.

Comment: Doesn't this just get the title of the one link that has the matching id (assuming no duplicate ids)? I thought the point of the question was to go the other way - ie be able to click a link based on the the color (title).

Comment: Justin, I have tried this and it actually gets all the titles in the table and puts them in an array that I use to click each color and check to see if the background was set, although I need to the data-mce-color field also since that is what is set in html page.  <span style="background-color: #000000;">

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread it. Though I do not understand why the link is being used to get itself. I think this could have been written as `titles = b.table(:class => 'mceColorSplitMenu').links.collect(&:title)`

Comment: @Justin Ko: I don't know if I understand what I was thinking myself.  Much better as the one-liner.  Want to post it as an answer or want me to edit the current answer?  Either way is good to me, and thanks for looking.

Comment: @coolercargo: Looking back, this is an unnecessarily complex statement.  For tutorials, you could do worse than working line-by-line through Justin's and Željko Filipin's answers.  They are the top watir users on SO who have put time/effort into solutions to real world problems.

Comment: @orde, your answer is right. The one liner is just a refactoring, so does not make much sense add as a new answer.